# Laravel Database connection not working as it should

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am currently setting up a Laravel installation and running through a tutorial to familiarize myself with this new framework.
I have managed to install composer and the Laravel base installation fine, but when i attempt to create a new database and seed it using artisan, nothing actually happens. Artisan tells me that is has seeded it fine but nothing seems to change in MYSQL.

My WAMP server is running on a local machine with Apache and PHPMyadmin and is setup correctly and has no issues (been using it for many projects before.)

Here are my database config settings:

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'celebrity_v1',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

I had to set the database up manually as even though the Artisan migrate command said it was working, it wouldn't actually create a new table, same with the seed. 
My commands are as follows:

```
php artisan migrate:make create_comments_table --create=comments
php artisan migrate
```

And to seed:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Can anyone see any problems with anything I am attempting to do here or suggest why I am having these issues? I don't have a lot of experience with Laravel.
Thanks

Comment: Did you set this configuration values in the `/app/config/database.php` file or in an environment directory like `/app/config/local/database.php`?

Comment: Hi, I set these values in the app/config/database.php file. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Did you fill the `up` method in the migration generated file?

Comment: Yes I did. it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Your `default` param value is set to `mysql` as well, isn't?

Comment: Please put your migration `up` method and your seeders `run` method in the question if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the values in /app/config/local/database.php instead of app/config/database.php

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please extend your answer in order to make it more valuable to other users and people seeking for this answer (like including an example) :)